# Accessing data inside nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested

I'm making a fairly complex menu system where it should change depending on the authority that has logged in. Now my question is, have I nested it too much? How do I access for example a title in the items, in the admin within the menus? I'm gonna generate the menus using angularJS's ng-repeat so I need to be able to access it via "item in menus.admin.items.title" for example. I figured I should ask now before I add more in case this isn't a viable option.

This is my menu structure inside the angular controller:

```
$scope.menus = [{
    admin: [{
        title: 'Administration',
        items: [{
                title: 'Hantera utbildningar',
                URL: 'mngprograms'
            },
            {
                title: 'Hantera kurser',
                URL: 'mngcourses'
            },
            {
                title: 'Hantera lärare',
                URL: 'mngteachers'
            },
            {
                title: 'Hantera studenter',
                URL: 'mngstudents'
            }],
        URL: 'administration',
        id: 'administration'
    }]
}]
```

Here's my failed attempt at accessing it:

**EDIT**:

To get a clearer view of the whole thing go here: http://jsfiddle.net/52evmfg9/

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="menu in menus" id="{{menu.id}}"><a href="{{menu.URL}}.php">{{menu.title}}</a>
        <ul data-ng-if="menu.admin">
            <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in menu[3].admin.items"><a href="{{subitem.URL}}.php">{{subitem.title}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I write this?

Comment: looks fine to nest it like this. You can always access the data in the HTML (in ng-repeat) and pass it to the controller with a function.

Comment: `subitem in menus[0].admin[0].items`

Comment: @EliteOctagon take a look at my edit, how would I write it in the ng-repeater?

Comment: @LcLk Didn't work either

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, what do you mean not working? can you show the contents of your `<li>`

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your line item. should it not be menus.admin.items? you have menu.admin.items

Comment: menus is an array of objects, which contains an array of objects, which contains an array of objects... nested repeaters are the way to go, unless you know the structure ahead of time... then you can access the first object in the array... subitem in menus[0].admin[0].items like LcLk says

Comment: @LcLk http://jsfiddle.net/52evmfg9/ here's the whole thing, sorry I forgot to include the whole html. It should be clearer now

Comment: working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WLnXBQbbOqveJuHiUeEI?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend making your hierarchy structure more explicit. For each menu, you can have a key "submenus" where you can find menus further down in the hierarchy. A useful directive for hiding elements is [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

I would only build one complete menu tree and then set permissions for your users or roles. Otherwise the tree will become unmanageable and there will be repeated data.

Here is an example jsBin:

http://jsbin.com/sixiw/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The thing is not all li elements has got a dropdown menu, so it's an inconsistent pattern with the ng-repeaters that makes me really confused, I'm completely lost on how to set up my repeaters so that they only display a submenu if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the comments:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(k,v) in menus"> 
       <div data-ng-repeat="(k,w) in v"> 
            <div data-ng-repeat="(k,x) in w">
                <ul data-ng-repeat="(k,y) in x" >
                    {{k}} : {{y}} 
                    <li ng-if="z.title" data-ng-repeat="(k,z) in y track by $index">
                        Title: {{z.title}} URL: {{z.URL}}
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WLnXBQbbOqveJuHiUeEI?p=preview

Comment: I'm a bit confused, if you take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/52evmfg9/
How would you implement your solution into my HTML there?